# Bicep - data factory identity property

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm running bicep 0.4.1318.

I have a "main" bicep module that calls a sub module to provision data factory:

```
var adfName = 'adf-ctaxrebate-${envPlusSuffix}-${formattedInstanceNum}'
module adfDeploy 'CTaxRebate.dataFactory.bicep' = {
  name: 'adfDeploy'
  params: {
    adfName: adfName
  }
}
```

The data factory module is as follows:

```
param adfName string

resource adf 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name:adfName
  location: resourceGroup().location
}

output dfId string = adf.identity.principalId
```

I used the PowerShell cdmlet New-AzResourceGroupDeployment to run the main bicep but I'm getting the following error:

> The template output 'dfId' is not valid: The language expression
> | property 'identity' doesn't exist, available properties are 'apiVersion, location, tags, etc...

I think this is trying to tell me that the following line from the adf module is wrong:

```
output dfId string = adf.identity.principalId
```

I'm puzzled by this since I've used the same code on a previous project and it works ok.

Also, the identity property does appear in the intellisense:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
identity: {
  type: 'SystemAssigned'
}
```

to the definition of your DataFactory in the module to tell the system it should generate a system assigned ID for you.